# Procedure or query to update another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

We have 2 tables

For Table 1 data gets updated from CSV format and it gets loaded in database in below format

```
id  YEAR    WEEK_NUM    MONDAY  TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY  FRIDAY  SATURDAY    SUNDAY
1   2017    37             8      8     8           8          8        
2   2017    37             8      8     8           8          8
```

Picking the year and Week_num it needs to update below table (which have dates 1-31)

```
ID  MONTH   YEAR    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
1   September   2017    8   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0   8   8   8   8   8   0   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0   0
2   September   2017    5   8   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   0   0   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0   0   8   8   8   8   8   0
```

in this case it need to update week 37 i.e sep 10-16 from table A.

Can anyone help me or guide me where to start it.

Comment: Why you have same week 37 on table 1 and same september 2017 on table 2?

Comment: You probably want unpivot your table first.